# Google Cloud Functions Datastore Connection issue

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

Few hours ago our application started to fail

```
Error: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
at (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:442)
```

As far as I know Client Libraries uses Applications Default Credentials approach in case if no permissions file passed into database connection instance, or if no env. variable specified. We didn't use any of this files on a remote Google Cloud Functions execution environment.

```
const db = new require("@google-cloud/datastore")();
```

And know I don't see any other way and generate credentials file and explicitly pass it during db initialization.

```
const db = new require("@google-cloud/datastore")({
    keyFilename: "./configs/db_key.json" 
});
```

If someone know the reason of such behavior - please share.

Comment: Google Cloud Functions is still in beta so this may be a service disruption issue. If your problem still persist after 24 hours consider reporting the issue via Google's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dialog with the Google Support we've found several things.

1. After few weeks I checked again and Application Default Credentials started to work again in GCF.
2. Support adviced to use additional service account like I did. In addition documentation contain this caution.

> Caution: The exact behavior of when the default service accounts are created and how they show up in your project might change in the future since they are designed to be used by Google Compute Engine and Google App Engine, so it is recommended that you don't rely on the existence of these default accounts for your use. It is recommended that you create additional service accounts explicitly using the IAM API, Cloud Platform Console or the gcloud tool for your long-term use. [Source](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed_service_accounts)

So, as it appears it is better to use explicit keys for every module and services that is used in your application. In addition here is the link to [service account best practices](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#best_practices)